# JMockit equivalent for whenNew

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, jmockit

In Powermock there is method `whenNew`.

I am new to Jmockit. I am migrating my application from Powermock to Jmockit.

Can you please tell me what is the equivalent for `whenNew` in Jmockit or how to implement the same in Jmockit? I really need this to be resolved to move forward.

The scenario is `new RestTemplate()` is used locally in different methods in a class ...with `whenNew` we can assign the mocked resttemplate value but not I am struggling to mock the same. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, usually adding a piece of code of what you already have helps in getting an answer. Could you add one?

Answer (score 2):

In your case, I think that what you're trying to do is to mock the construction of a new instance of RestTemplate.

You should take a look at JMockit's doc as its really well done and a lot of the questions are already answered there (in your case [here](http://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/Mocking.html#futureInstancesByConstructor)).

```
@Test
public void test(@Mocked RestTemplate restTemplateMock) {
   new Expectations() {{
      new RestTemplate(); result = restTemplateMock;

      restTemplateMock.method(); result = "something";
   }};

   // Code under test:
   new RestTemplate().method(); // will return "something"
}
```

Use the necessary constructor depending on the parameters you need to pass and I think this should help you.